# How does flash work?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've been playing lol for a long time and still I don't know how the summoner's spell Flash works technically speaking.

Here are my concerns : When you flash sometimes you still get negative effects even though you are out of range thanks to flash.
For instance, when Annie uses Tibbers and you flash at the same time, you're stunned and take the damage but your character is miles away from tibbers.

What causes a champion to still take damage/experience negative effects of skill shots that appear to land after they have Flashed?

Comment: Honestly, unless we get one of the devs in here, I don't think this question can be answered on a code level. My best guess is that the animation is played, then the character model's coordinates are simply changed to the cursor target, then before resolving it does calculations in order to not collide with terrain. FWIW I'm a programmer and this is how I would go about implementing Flash.

Comment: Maybe someone saw a frame by frame analysis of this spell or hacked it to see on some private server idk... But still i don't get why I get downvoted here. Everything is in the rules with my question :(

Comment: I think it's because you're technically asking for information that only the developers would have. I think the question is answerable from the standpoint of "Why does x happen when y?", but it doesn't follow the guidelines the way it's currently phrased.

Comment: Also a game dev and I agree with @nukeforum without an official Riot Dev you've no chance of a legit answer and I also second his implementation/guess. I don't agree in downvoting you for it but it is a question that is almost impossible to answer properly. Just ignore drive-by downvoters anyway. They should always give a reason.

Comment: @JohnnyBgud I made an edit to your question to make it answerable. Feel free to roll it back if you don't feel I've captured the spirit of your question.

Comment: Let me edit the final question so it matches these criterias then, it might be  a good idea indeed :)

Comment: well i clicked edit right at the same time haha. thanks mate

Answer (score 8):

The reason some skill-shot abilities still land even when flashing is the result of your character being hit during the wind-up animation, but before your character has been relocated.

Flash cannot be stopped once it has been initiated, so even if you get stunned/knocked-up/hooked, Flash will still move you the number of units it was designated.

Comment: To word it slightly differently, until the flash animation completes, your hitbox remains in the same location, so there is a split second at which your hitbox and character model are in two different locations.

Answer (score -3):

More than likely the issue you experienced is just client/server side lag.

A bug like this on the most popular summoner spell would have raised much attention and eyebrows.

Comment: It isn't lag, it is due to the animation taking time to complete. Your hitbox does not travel to the new location until your flash animation completes, thus your hitbox and your model are at two different points briefly. It is fairly well known throughout the community, and has been explained by different Riot employees. The one I specifically remember is Jatt, who explained it during a LAN tournament he was casting.

Comment: The disconnect between spell animation and effects is well known, especially for Tibbers. It's a clarity issue.

Comment: @Hackworth no intetional snark, but if it's well known and the employees talk about it, why haven't they fixed this yet? It shouldn't be impossible to move the hit boxes ahead of the animation completion.

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer you are replying to the wrong person I believe. Other than that, not only the employees know about it. There are plenty of threads with video about it on reddit. As for why Riot didn't fix it yet, you'd better ask Riot.